# Deleting list does not work: "List does not exist"

Tags: sharepoint, csom

When deleting a list a get the error "List does not exist" under certain circumstances. My sequence is:

```
try { deleteList("myList"); } catch { } // delete list in case it exists
createList("myList");
// Do something with the list. Does not matter
deleteList("myList");
```

If the list does not exist at the time I run the code all works fine. If however the list exists I get the error. When I step through the code I can see (in the browser) that the list really gets deleted and re-created.

When I create a new clientContext between createList() and deleteList() then it works. I assume something in the clientContext is messed up.

I do not think it has to do with my functions but in any case, here they are:

```
    public void CreateList(string title)
    {
        ListCreationInformation lci = new ListCreationInformation();
        lci.Title = title;
        lci.TemplateType = (int)ListTemplateType.GenericList;
        List spList = context.Web.Lists.Add(lci);
        context.Load(spList);
        spList.Update();
        context.ExecuteQuery();
    }

    public void DeleteList(string listname)
    {
        List spList = context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(listname);
        spList.DeleteObject();
        context.ExecuteQuery();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Johannes I will talk about the case where you code fails where list exists already.

1. First you get ClientContext which has information of all lists including your list : myList
2. Then you call function deleteList("myList"); which will delete your list without any issue.
3. But when you try to re-create list with same name with old ClientContext it will error out because it has information of sharepoint state before you deleted list.

Hence due to inconsistency in Context,  It will error out. So as you mentioned, simply create new ClientContext after deleting "myList" and it will work just fine.

Comment: Thank for this confirmation. I really appreciate.
Would there be a possibility to do it without re-creating the client context, e.g. by clearing off the stored state in the client context.

Comment: Remove ExecuteQuery() from all the functions like : CreateList(string title) and DeleteList(string listname) and call it ONLY ONCE at end of your code. Not sure if it will work or not.